# Display Specific Color in Every Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, geometry, sql-server-2012

I have a table where one column is of type `geometry`. The table has three rows in total.

Is it possible to specify the color used for each row's `geometry` in the **Spatial results** tab in query results in SQL Management Studio?

[image: query results]

For example, I would like to specify that the first row should be red, the second yellow, and the third black.

Comment: Displayed where?  In the Data Grid output of SQL Server?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/isaac/WindowsLiveWriter/EyeCandyoftheHighestOrder_839F/image_thumb_4.png

This picture can give you an answer. Please inform me if you neeed more information

Comment: Ah! Lol - I'm half asleep this morning; missed the Geometry bit!

Comment: Is this the free app (by Craig Dunn) for viewing the spatial data?

Comment: There's quite an [interesting piece here](http://conceptdev.blogspot.co.uk/2008/01/geoquery-2008-beta-polygons-on-sphere.html) about rendering colour onto his GeoQuery app.

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003606

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently (ie in SQL Server 2012) **not** possible to control the colors used in the Spatial Results tab,, per [this Connect item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/693327/ssms-spatial-results-tab-colour-features-by-value-in-chosen-column) :

> We took a look at this feature request recently and triaged it against
>   several others and unfortunately, it did not meet the bar to be fixed.
>   While we are closing this issue as 'won't fix', we have taken note of
>   this internally and we will try & incorporate this request when we
>   revisit this functionality in a future release of SSMS. Regards,
>   Sanjay Nagamangalam, SQL Server Manageability